# passing an object in R, with multiple variable names, to order / sort a data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I have a data frame say:

```
var1 <- c(7,2,8,4,4)

var2 <- c('m' , 'f' , 'm' , 'f' , 'm')

var3 <- c('x' , 'x' , 'x' , 'y' , 'x')

df <- data.frame(var1 , var1 , var3)
```

Now I want to sort the data on var2, var3, var1, and I have an object:

```
var_sort <- 'var2, var3, var1'
```

Which I extracted from another data frame.

So I use the following code (dplyr):

```
sorted <- df %>%
            arrange(var_sort)
```

and get the following error:

```
Error: incorrect size (1), expecting :1439
```

I also tried the following, but only sorted on the first variable:

```
test <- as.vector(strsplit(var_sort , ', '))

sorted <- df %>%
  arrange_(.dots = test)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"test" is still a `list` of length `1`.  You need to convert it to `vector` or use `as.list`.

```
 df %>%
     arrange_(.dots=as.list(test[[1]]))
 #    var1 var2 var3
 #1    2    f    x
 #2    4    f    y
 #3    4    m    x
 #4    7    m    x
 #5    8    m    x
```

Or

```
df %>%
   arrange_(.dots=test[[1]])
```

which is the same as

```
df %>%
    arrange(var1, var2, var3)
#   var1 var2 var3
#1    2    f    x
#2    4    f    y
#3    4    m    x
#4    7    m    x
#5    8    m    x
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
```